# Google Slides not seeing meeting in calendar

Tags: google-calendar, google-hangouts, google-slides

Google Slides recently added the ability to present from an Android device to a Google Hangouts meeting. I have meetings scheduled in my primary Google Calendar. However, when I try to present to a Hangout, my screen says "No scheduled meetings". How can I get Slides to notice that a meeting is in my calendar?

[Edit] It seems to work OK if I create the meeting. However, it cannot see meetings that I have been invited to, even though I accepted and said "Yes, I will attend."

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that it's working as was designed.

From [Present slides - Google Docs Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1696787?hl=en)

> To present in a meeting you've already set up, touch its title in the
>   menu.

If you would like to see a new feature or that an existing features works different, send your comments directly to Google. You could do that directly from your Slides mobile app or from the Slides web App. Also you could do that using the Google Docs Help Forum.